# How to keep JSONArray elements in the same order as the class in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have the following snippet of code, where I take the books from the ArrayList booksList and put their values in a JSONObject, which then goes in a JSONArray. The idea is to create a .json file with the books in a particular order, specified by me:

```
 JSONArray JSONbookList = new JSONArray();
        Collections.sort(booksList);
        //JSONbookList = new JSONArray(booksList); 
        for (Book book : booksList) {
            JSONObject bookJson = new JSONObject();
            bookJson.put("ID", book.getBookID().trim());
            bookJson.put("Name", book.getBookName().trim().replace("\n        ", " "));
            bookJson.put("ISBN", book.getBookISBN().trim());
            bookJson.put("AuthorID", book.getBookAuthor().trim());
            bookJson.put("Disp", book.getBookDisp().trim());
            JSONbookList.put(bookJson);
            
        }
```

this is the book class for reference:

```
package p2;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Book implements Serializable , Comparable<Book>{

    private String identificador;
    private String nombre;
    private String autor;
    private String disponible;
    private String ISBN;

    public Book (String id, String name, String aut, String disp, String isbn) {
    this.identificador = id;
    this.nombre = name;
    this.autor = aut;
    this.disponible = disp;
    this.ISBN = isbn;
    }
    
    public Book getBook(String bookId) {
    if (this.identificador.equals(bookId)) {
        return this;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
    }

    //Getters
    
    public String getBookID () {
    return this.identificador;
    }

    public String getBookName () {
    return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getBookAuthor () {
    return this.autor;
    }

    public String getBookDisp () {
    return this.disponible;
    }

    public String getBookISBN () {
    return this.ISBN;
    }

    //Setters
    
    public void setBookID (String id) {
    this.identificador = id;
    }

    public void setBookName (String name) {
    this.nombre = name;
    }

    public void setBookAuthor (String aut) {
    this.autor = aut;
    }

    public void setBookDisp (String disp) {
    this.disponible = disp;
    }

    public void setBookISBN (String isbn) {
    this.ISBN = isbn;
    }

   public int compareTo(Book libro) {
    String id1 = this.identificador;
    String id2 = libro.identificador;
    //Comparar alfabeticamente
    return id1.compareTo(id2);
}


    public String toString() {
    return "Book{" +
        "identificador='" + identificador + '\'' +
        ", nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
        ", autor='" + autor + '\'' +
        ", disponible='" + disponible + '\'' +
        ", ISBN='" + ISBN + '\'' +
        '}';
    }
    
}
```

Ideally, the JSONObject would keep the same order of attributes as the class, or atleast, the order in which im putting them in, but it seems to use an arbitrary order. Now, if I'm not mistaken, this is intended behaviour from the JSONObject class, but apparently, the JSONArray class should keep the order of values, but how can I use a JSONArray without a JSONObject?

For example, here is one of the books as it is displayed in the json file:

```
{"Disp":"no","AuthorID":"4","ISBN":"9781427900792","ID":"104","Name":"Los baños de Argel"},
```

The desired output would be

```
{"id":"104","Name":"Los baños de Argel","AuthorID":"4","Disp":"no","ISBN":"9781427900792"}
```

Meaning that the pair of keys/values would be displayed in the same order as the order they are put into the JSONObject. Using a JSONObject is not mandatory necessarily, but it seems like the only way to work with JSONArrays, and the output does need to be a JSONArray/.json file.

This is a small part of an assignment so alternatives like the Jackson library are out of the question.

I have also tried putting the Book Objects into a LinkedHashMap but it doesn't seem to work like that, the JSONObject will always disorganize them, since it uses a regular HashMap if I'm not mistaken, so it gave the same result as the ArrayList, meaning that the class that I use to store my objects doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: An object is an "*unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs"*, while an array is "*an ordered sequence of zero or more values"*. The question is unclear. Do you want the field of the object to have a fixed order (this is not possible according to  RFC 7159), or do you want the elements in the array to have a fixed order (this is possible according to RFC 7159)? Please [edit] the post and clarify.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the feedback, I will edit the post with an example.

Comment: Depending on the order of fields of a json object is highly discouraged since [RFC 7159 (`datatracker.ietf.org`)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159/) explicitly says that field in an object are unordered. Why do you want/need to order the fields?

Comment: @Turing85, that's an _[RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)_.

Comment: @Reilas I know. I wrote "RFC". Your point?

Comment: For completion: RFC 7159 is obsolted by [RFC 8259 (`datatracker.ietf.org`)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259). The two sentences I mentioned earlier are still present in RFC 8259.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The idea is to create a .json file with the books in a particular order ...
>
>
>
> ... Meaning that the pair of keys/values would be displayed in the same order as the order they are put into the JSONObject. ..."*

If you have no objection with using *[Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)*, here is an example.

```java
Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
record Book(String id, String name, String author, String available, String isbn) { }
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new Book("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"));
    add(new Book("b", "b", "b", "b", "b"));
    add(new Book("c", "c", "c", "c", "c"));
}};
String s = g.toJson(books, List.class);
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "name": "a",
    "author": "a",
    "available": "a",
    "isbn": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "name": "b",
    "author": "b",
    "available": "b",
    "isbn": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": "c",
    "name": "c",
    "author": "c",
    "available": "c",
    "isbn": "c"
  }
]
```

Comment: GSON does not make any guarantee on field order. Thus, we rely on undocumented behaviour that could change without prior notice.

Comment: @Turing85, too funny.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Im not allowed to use any other libraries other than the json one